# Find the minimum value of $x$ in the given that $\frac{\sqrt{2x^2-1} + \sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt2x^2}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, radicals

How to simplify the given equation and find the minimum value of $x$ ?
$$\frac{\sqrt{2x^2-1} + \sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt2x^2}=1$$
I do square both sides but I doesn't make any sense

Comment: $t=x^2$ makes stuff easier.

Comment: And after *that*, use $\beta=2t^2-3t+2$ and obtain the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $t=x^2$ and clear denominators to get
$$\sqrt{2t-1}+\sqrt{t-1}=\sqrt{2}t.$$
Squaring both sides shows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
2t^2&=&(2t-1)+2\sqrt{(2t-1)(t-1)}+(t-1)\\
&=&3t-2+2\sqrt{2t^2-3t+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Isolating the square root and squaring again shows that
$$(2t^2-3t+2)^2=4(2t^2-3t+1).$$
Rearranging yields the quartic equation
$$4t^4-12t^3+9t^2=t^2(2t-3)^2=0.$$
Of course $t=0$ is impossible, so we see that $t=\tfrac32$ and so $x=\sqrt{\tfrac32}$. This shows that the minimum value for $x$ equals $\sqrt{\tfrac32}$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $u = x^2 - 1, v = x^2 \implies \sqrt{u+v} + \sqrt{u} = v\sqrt{2}\implies \sqrt{u+v} = v\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{u}\implies u+v = 2v^2-2\sqrt{2}v\sqrt{u}+u\implies 2v^2 - v - 2\sqrt{2}v\sqrt{u} = 0\implies v(2v-1-2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{u}) = 0\implies v = 0\implies x^2=0 \implies x = 0$ , or $2v= 1+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{u}\implies 2(u+1) = 1 +2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{u}\implies 2u -2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{u} + 1 = 0\implies (\sqrt{2u} - 1)^2 = 0\implies \sqrt{2u} = 1\implies 2u = 1\implies 2(x^2-1) = 1\implies 2x^2 = 3\implies x = \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{2}$ . But $x = 0$ is not a solution,so the solutions are : $ x=\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{2}$.

Comment: $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\sqrt{2x^2-1}\ge0,v=\sqrt{x^2-1}\ge0$
$\implies u^2-v^2=x^2$

and $ u+v=\sqrt2(u^2-v^2)$

If $u+v=0,\sqrt{2x^2-1}=\sqrt{x^2-1}=0$ which is untenable

$\implies u-v=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\implies \sqrt2v=\sqrt2u-1$

and $u^2-2v^2=1\implies  u^2-(\sqrt2u-1)^2=1$

$\implies 0=(u-\sqrt2)^2$

$u(\ne0)=?$

$x^2=\dfrac{u^2+1}2=?$

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Servaes, Can you find $u$ from here?

Comment: I just have a hard time parsing what is going on. You use a lot of '$\implies$' and $\iff$' when I think you mean something like *"It follows that..."*.

Comment: @Servaes, $$\iff$$  implies & is implied by.

Comment: I understand that, but for example, you write that
$$u^2-2v^2=1\iff u^2-(\sqrt2u-1)^2=1,$$
which really doesn't make any sense to me, and is an abuse of the '$\iff$' symbol also by your definition. I'm guessing you mean to say something like
$$"\text{Also note that we have } u^2-2v^2=1\text{, and substituting the above then yields } u^2-(\sqrt{2}u-1)^2=1."$$
I made this guess while already knowing the answer, and even then I've had to check a few other guesses on where these identities might have come from (my third guess was correct).

Comment: All in all it doesn't seem helpful to someone who doesn't already know the answer, or at least roughly where to look for it, and it abuses notation quite badly in my opinion.

Comment: @Servaes, Please find the updated answer. Hope you have understood the difference between  $\implies$ and $\iff$

Comment: I stand by my earlier comment on the abuse of '$\implies$'.